# Calculate the value of the fraction $\frac{3sin^2x+4cos^2x}{5sin^2x+8sinxcosx}$ if $ntg(x) = 1.5$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]Calculate the value of the fraction $\frac{3sin^2x+4cos^2x}{5sin^2x+8sinxcosx}$ if $ntg(x) = 1.5$.

This would be an easy task if $tg(x)=1.5$, but I have no clue how to solve this particular task. Please provide a hint.

Right answer is $\frac{12}{17}$

Comment: sorry the notation is not that clear. Do you mean $tg(x) = tan(x)$ and $ntg(x) = \frac{1}{tan(x)}$?

Comment: $tg(x) = tan(x) $. But I do not know what does $ntg(x)$ means

Comment: @RahulMadhavan I added the picture of the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Rahul mentioned in comments, if $\widetilde{n}tg(x) = \frac1{\tan x} = \cot x = 1.5$, then

$$\frac{3\sin^2x+4\cos^2x}{5\sin^2x+8\sin x\cos x} = \frac{3+4\frac{\cos^2x}{\sin^2x}}{5+8\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}}=\frac{3+4\cot^2x}{5+8\cot x}=\frac{3+4(\frac{9}{4})}{5+8(\frac32)}=\frac{12}{17}$$